# How to close window (NSWindowController) by hitting the ESC key?

Tags: macos, cocoa, first-responder, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

#### Issue

I would like the user being able to close a window by hitting the ESC key but I can't get it to work in this specific case, hitting ESC triggers an error sound (the "no you can't do that" macOS bloop) and nothing happens.

#### Context

I'm making a subclass of NSWindowController which itself creates an instance of a subclass of NSViewController and sets it in a view. Both controllers have their own xib file.

NSWindowController:

```
final class MyWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var targetView: MainView!

    let myVC: MyViewController!
    var params: SomeParams!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        myVC = MyViewController(someParams: params)
        myVC.view.setFrameSize(targetView.frame.size)
        myVC.view.setBoundsSize(targetView.bounds.size)
        targetView.addSubview(myVC.view)
    }

    override var windowNibName: String! {
        return "MyWindowController"
    }

    convenience init(someParams params: SomeType) {
        self.init(window: nil)
        self.params = params
    }

}
```

NSViewController:

```
final class MyViewController: NSViewController {

    convenience init(someParams params: SomeType) {
        // do stuff with the params
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // configure stuff for the window
    }

}
```

#### What I've tried

I *suppose* that my issue is that the MyWindowController NSWindow is the `.initialFirstResponder` when I would want the content of the `targetView` (an NSTableView) to be the first responder - this way I could use `keyDown`, I guess, and send the close command to the window from there. This doesn't seem optimal, though.

I've tried forcing the view controller views into being the first responder by using `window?.makeFirstResponder(theView)` in the windowDidLoad of MyWindowController but nothing ever changes.

I've also tried adding this to MyWindowController:

```
override func cancelOperation(_ sender: Any?) {
    print("yeah, let's close!")
}
```

But this only works *if the user clicks first on the background of the window* then hits ESC, and it still emits the error sound anyway. Which is actually what made me think that the issue was about the first responder being on the window.

#### Question

How would you achieve that? Of course, I know that the user can already close the window with CMD+W, but I'd really like to sort out this issue nonetheless.

*Note that the code example is in Swift but I can also accept explanations using Objective-C.*

Comment: Try `- (void)cancel:(id)sender`.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't show up in Xcode's autocompletion ([screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/a2UBsBUptfwkvXFERolJilE6XMCHHr)).

Comment: In that case you'll have type it yourself or use `cancelOperation` and remove "Operation".

Comment: @Willeke Wow. It works! I suppose there's a bug in Xcode 8, autocompletion should definitely show that. Thanks! And please add that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation of `cancelOperation` explains how `cancelOperation` should work:

> This method is bound to the Escape and Command-. (period) keys. The key window first searches the view hierarchy for a view whose key equivalent is Escape or Command-., whichever was entered. If none of these views handles the key equivalent, the window sends a default action message of `cancelOperation:` to the first responder and from there the message travels up the responder chain.
>
> If no responder in the responder chain implements `cancelOperation:`, the key window searches the view hierarchy for a view whose key equivalent is Escape (note that this may be redundant if the original key equivalent was Escape). If no such responder is found, then a `cancel:` action message is sent to the first responder in the responder chain that implements it.
>
> `NSResponder` declares but does not implement this method.

`NSWindow` implements `cancelOperation:` and the next responder, the window controller, isn't checked for an implementation of `cancelOperation:`. The `cancel:` message does arrive at the window controller. Implementing

```
- (void)cancel:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"cancel");
}
```

will work. The `cancel:` message isn't inherited from a superclass so autocompletion doesn't suggest it.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2:

```
@objc func cancel(_ sender: Any?) {
    close()
}
```

I tried it before but without the `@objc` part and it didn't work. So don't omit it.

Answer (score 2):

When I needed such behavior I implemented it by overriding keyDown: of the NSWindow object.

I.e. something like the following:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    int k = [theEvent keyCode];
    if (k == kVK_Escape)
    {
        [self close];
        return;
    }

    [super keyDown:theEvent];
}
```

Comment: I tried that some time ago - but I'm using `class MyWindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate` so I didn't see how I could use an NSWindow subclass...

Comment: If you create your NSWindow object via xib then just describe somewhere class MyWindow : NSWindow with this method, and set object's class to MyWindow instead of NSWindow

Comment: Thank you for this information. I ended up implementing Willeke's solution which is perfect for me.